# passing PaintEventArgs to my function causes an error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried to create a function that draws my map. My function is like this :

```
public void DrawMap(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    List<Point> lstPointLeft = new List<Point>();

    foreach (var t in lstSensorLeft)
    {
        Point objPoint = new Point(t.XLocation, t.YLocation);
        lstPointLeft.Add(objPoint);
        Rectangle rectSens = new Rectangle(t.XLocation, t.YLocation, 3, 3);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, rectSens);
        if (t.StationId != null)
        {
            Rectangle rectEhsansq = new Rectangle(t.XLocation - 6, t.YLocation - 6, 12, 12);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rectEhsansq);

        }
    }

    List<Point> lstPointRight = new List<Point>();

    foreach (var t in lstSensorRight)
    {
        Point objPoint = new Point(t.XLocation + 30, t.YLocation + 30);
        lstPointRight.Add(objPoint);
        Rectangle rectSens = new Rectangle(t.XLocation + 30, t.YLocation + 30, 3, 3);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, rectSens);
        if (t.StationId != null)
        {
            Rectangle rectPosition = new Rectangle(t.XLocation + 24, t.YLocation + 24, 12, 12);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rectPosition);

            Rectangle rectTrainState = new Rectangle(t.XLocation + 27, t.YLocation + 27, 7, 7);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(RedBrush, rectTrainState);

        }
    }


    e.Graphics.DrawLines(pLine, lstPointLeft.ToArray());
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(pLine, lstPointRight.ToArray());
    //ShowOnlineTrain(e);
    //Thread newThread = new Thread(() => ShowOnlineTrain(e));
    //newThread.Start();
}
```

This function draws my map, I have a `PictureBox` in my form that shows my map. This function `DrawMap` draws a railway map without anything. My problem is how do I call this function in `page_Load`? I have tried something like this :

I have created a global painteventarg:

```
private PaintEventArgs a;
```

And in `form_load` I am doing this :

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DrawMap(a);

}
```

In this line :

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, rectSens);
```

I am getting below error :

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PresentationLayer.PreLayer.frmMain.DrawMap(PaintEventArgs e)
```

Comment: any of the object is null.

Comment: i think it because i pass the **painteventarg a** as a null

Comment: Call DrawMap(a); in frmMain__paint event you can use Paint event of form

Comment: @saeed i did that before ,but i need to write my own draw map ,because i need to call my function everytime that i need ,but using paintevent i can't do that

Comment: Why are you sending a painteventarg to your function? Does it really need this parameter? If it does, why are you sending in a null value? Is this code that you've written or have you found it somewhere and just copied and pasted it without understanding it?

Comment: You know i write this code and i understand it ,before posting this post ,my program works fine because i put the **Drawmap** function into **paint** event of picturebox but i need to a function that draws my map into picturebox just it ,i don't know what exactly **painteventarg** is ? and i have to pass this to my function because i got a lot of errors ,i just want to draw my map ?just it !

Comment: @o_weisman thanks ,you are right i removed **painteventarg ** and my errors is solved but when i call drawmap function it just show the map for one second and it disappears

Comment: Passing PaintEventArgs looks ugly to me!!!You can do this in Paint event of picture box it's a fast solution.Whenever you want to paint it again call PictureBox.Invalidate() method

Comment: Passing `PaintEventArgs`, or better, just the `e.Graphics` object is fine. But you __need__ to do this from the respective `Paint` event!!

Comment: I don't understand: If it worked ok when it was called from the picture box's paint event, why did you change it? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that your `DrawMap` method should be taking a `Graphics` object as a parameter rather than a `PaintEventArgs`:

```
public void DrawMap(Graphics g)
{
    ...
    g.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, rectSens);
    ...
}
```

Then you can pass it the graphics object of the thing you want to draw the map on. e.g. [Get the graphics object of an image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx).

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image img = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
    DrawMap(g);
    myPictureBox.Image = img;
}
```

This could be done in any method, not just in the Load event, but note, you may need to refresh the control after drawing on it to see any changes.

```
myPictureBox.Refresh();
```

Alternatively, you could [get the graphics object from a control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Graphics g = myPictureBox.CreateGraphics()
DrawMap(g);
```

However, if you use this then you might have issues with the control re-drawing itself and clearing your map (e.g. when the control or window is resized or hidden by another window).  In this case it is always best to put your drawing in the Paint event of the control.